# JavaScript: LeetCode 'Plus One' recursion timeout problem

Tags: javascript, recursion

Plus one- leetcode problem

Problem:

> You are given a large integer represented as an integer array digits,
> where each digits[i] is the ith digit of the integer. The digits are
> ordered from most significant to least significant in left-to-right
> order. The large integer does not contain any leading 0's.

Increment the large integer by one and return the resulting array of digits.

Example 1:

```
Input: digits = [1,2,3]
Output: [1,2,4]
Explanation: The array represents the integer 123.
Incrementing by one gives 123 + 1 = 124.
Thus, the result should be [1,2,4].
```

Example 2:

```
Input: digits = [9]
Output: [1,0]
Explanation: The array represents the integer 9.
Incrementing by one gives 9 + 1 = 10.
Thus, the result should be [1,0].
```

Constraints:

- 1 <= digits.length <= 100
- 0 <= digits[i] <= 9
- digits does not contain any leading 0's.

My solution:

```js
// [9] becomes [1,0]
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    let len = digits.length;
    //count array backwards
    for(let i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // if the currently indexed value is 9, we will zero it (line 14)
        // we will also check if the previous entry is 9 via recursion (line 19)
        // if it is not 9, we increment it by 1 and return 'digits' (lines 22, 23)
        // if there is no previous entry we prepend one and return 'digits' (lines 16, 17)
        if(digits[i] == 9) {
            digits[i] = 0;
            if(!digits[i - 1]){
                digits.unshift(1);
                return digits;
            } else {
                plusOne(digits.slice(0, i-1));
            }
        } else {
            digits[i] = digits[i] + 1;
            return digits;
        }
    }
};

let array = [9,9,9];

console.log(plusOne(array));

// This code breaks on input:
// [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
```

The difficulty with this problem is with 9's, which naturally increment the place value of its more significant neighbor.

I address this problem with recursion. (As you can read in the code comments).

The problem is that I am getting a 'Time limit exceeded' error on Leetcode on the following input:

`[9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]`.

Though it appears to pass all other test cases.

Is this a stack size issue? Is there a way to optimize the space complexity of the above code?

Thank you very much.

I have no idea how to reduce the time/space complexity of the problem as I am new to recursion.

Comment: What is `plusOne(digits.slice(0, i-1));`? It does nothing. It only wastes CPU cycles. Remove it. `digits.slice(0, i-1)` creates a shallow copy of the array. The return value is discarded. This function call has no observable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there a way to optimize the space complexity of the above code?"*

Yes, remove the unnecessary recursive call. It does nothing:

```js
// [9] becomes [1,0]
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    let len = digits.length;
    //count array backwards
    for(let i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // if the currently indexed value is 9, we will zero it (line 14)
        // we will also check if the previous entry is 9 via recursion (line 19)
        // if it is not 9, we increment it by 1 and return 'digits' (lines 22, 23)
        // if there is no previous entry we prepend one and return 'digits' (lines 16, 17)
        if(digits[i] == 9) {
            digits[i] = 0;
            if(i === 0){
                digits.unshift(1);
                return digits;
            }
        } else {
            digits[i] = digits[i] + 1;
            return digits;
        }
    }
};

let array = [9,9,9];

console.log(plusOne(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to traverse the entire input. The function can stop as soon as there's no carry to the next decimal place.

```js
var plusOne = function(digits) {
  // a single digit add that returns [sum, carry]
  const incr = num => num === 9 ? [0, 1] : [num + 1, 0];
  // reverse the input so we can go least significant to most
  const reversed = digits.reverse();
  let index = 0,
    carry = 0,
    sum = 0;

  // increment digits, stopping as soon as there's no carry
  // worst case is a run through a lot of 9s  
  do {
    [sum, carry] = incr(reversed[index]);
    reversed[index] = sum;
  } while (carry && ++index < reversed.length)

  // push a 1 if we got to the most significant digit with a carry
  if (carry) reversed.push(1);
  return reversed.reverse();
}

// here it is running pretty fast on 10x the largest input
let lottaNines = Array(1000).fill(9);
console.log(plusOne(lottaNines))
```

Comment: The code in the question already stops when there is no carry. It's the `else` case with a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that :

```js
const plusOne = arr =>
  {
  let 
    rem = 1
  , res = []
    ;
  for (let i=arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    res[i] = arr[i] + rem;
    rem    = res[i] > 9 ? 1 : 0;
    if (rem)
      res[i] = 0;
    }
  if (rem )
    res.unshift(1);
  return res;
  }

console.log( JSON.stringify(plusOne([1,2,3])))
console.log( JSON.stringify(plusOne([9])))
 
const outOfMaxInteger =[9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]

console.log( JSON.stringify(plusOne(outOfMaxInteger)))
```

> in fact it amounts to making a school addition:

```js
const arrAdd= (arrA,arrB) =>
  {
  let 
    iA = arrA.length -1
  , iB = arrB.length -1
  , res = []
  , rem = 0
    ;
  for (let i = 1 + Math.max(iA,iB); i--; iA--,iB--)
    {
    res[i]  = rem + (iA<0?0:arrA[iA]) + (iB<0 ? 0:arrB[iB]);
    rem     = 0 | (res[i] / 10);
    res[i] %= 10;
    }
  if (rem) res.unshift(rem);
  return res;
  }

console.log( '  [1,2,3] +   [1] =', JSON.stringify(arrAdd(   [1,2,3],  [1])))
console.log( '[1,2,3,0] + [8,0] =', JSON.stringify(arrAdd( [1,2,3,0],[8,0])))
console.log( '  [1,9,3] +   [8] =', JSON.stringify(arrAdd(   [1,9,3],  [8])))
console.log( '      [9] +   [9] =', JSON.stringify(arrAdd(       [9],  [9])))
```